# Find the days lag and replace 0 with last day lag pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a df containing employee , worked_days and sold columns
Some employee sold only for first day and after five days sold another

My data look like this

```
data = {'id':[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], 
    'days':[1, 3, 3, 8, 8,8, 3, 8, 8, 9, 9, 12],
    'sold':[1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data) 
df['days_lag'] = df.groupby('id')['days'].diff().fillna(0).astype('int16')
```

Gives me this

```
    id  days  sold  days_lag
0    1     1     1         0
1    1     3     0         2
2    1     3     1         0
3    1     8     1         5
4    1     8     1         0
5    1     8     0         0
6    2     3     0         0
7    2     8     1         5
8    2     8     1         0
9    2     9     2         1
10   2     9     0         0
11   2    12     1         3
```

I want the results to be like below

```
    id  days  sold  days_lag
0    1     1     1         0
1    1     3     0         2
2    1     3     1         2
3    1     8     1         5
4    1     8     1         5
5    1     8     0         5
6    2     3     0         0
7    2     8     1         5
8    2     8     1         5
9    2     9     2         1
10   2     9     0         1
11   2    12     1         3
```

How can i achieve this ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

```
In [92]: df['days_lag'] = df.groupby('id')['days'].diff().fillna(0).astype('int16')
In [96]: df['days_lag'] = df.groupby(['id', 'days'])['days_lag'].transform('max')

In [97]: df
Out[97]: 
    id  days  sold  days_lag
0    1     1     1         0
1    1     3     0         2
2    1     3     1         2
3    1     8     1         5
4    1     8     1         5
5    1     8     0         5
6    2     3     0         0
7    2     8     1         5
8    2     8     1         5
9    2     9     2         1
10   2     9     0         1
11   2    12     1         3
```